# C# nameof(Class) equivalent in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

In C# we have nameof() operator which return name of the class in string, what is the equivalent in Kotlin?

My use case would be something like this for

```
internal val TAG = nameof(MyCustomActivity)
```

Comment: `internal val TAG = MyCustomActivity::class.simpleName`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
MyCustomActivity::class.simpleName
```

Will output `MyCustomActivity`

```
MyCustomActivity::class.qualifiedName
```

Will output `<your_package>.MyCustomActivity`

Answer (score 10):

As [mentioned in the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63211748/409279), the `<class>::class.simpleName` property will provide a result similar to that of the C# `nameof` operator. However, unlike `nameof`, `::class.*` cannot be evaluated at compile-time.

This is relevant, as cases where you may use the `nameof` operator in C#, you cannot equivalently do with `::class`

For example, AspectJ's `@Around` annotation.

The following will fail, as you cannot interpolate non-compile-time**†** expressions:

```kotlin
@Around("@annotation(${MyAnnotation::class.simpleName})")
```

If Kotlin supported `nameof` in the same fashion as C# (*where it can be used in that context*) one could do this:

```kotlin
@Around("@annotation(${nameof(MyAnnotation)})")
```

So, while the accepted answer provides a functionally similar manner of resolving symbol names in Kotlin, it cannot be used with the same flexibility as `nameof` in C#.

---

**†** Interestingly, until writing this answer I didn't realize you can interpolate constant value (*and other compile-time evaluable*) expressions into annotation parameters; the following **will** compile:

```kotlin
const val FOO = "foo"

@MyAnnotation("${FOO} ${1 + 1}")
```